# Minify JS Files with Webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to use the webpack to minify all my js, .css, images and fonts files. As I am studying the Webpack, I am trying first with the JS files.
In my js folder I have the files jquery-2.2.3.min.js, bootstrap.min.js, easing.js, move-top.js and SmoothScroll.min.js.
when i try to run npm start it generates the error Error: Conflict: Multiple chunks iss assets to the same filename principal.js (chunks jquery and bootstrap).
Below is my webpack.config.js:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        jquery: './js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js',
        bootstrap: './js/bootstrap.min.js',
        easing: './js/easing.js',
        move_top: './js/move-top.js',
        smooth_scroll: './js/SmoothScroll.min.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'default.js',
        path: __dirname + '/public'
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "style.css"
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules:[
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        'css-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                    use: [
                        'file-loader'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

Comment: jQuery and bootstrap, at least, are already compiled and minified. Don't run them through webpack. If you want to import jQuery, then don't add an entry file for jQuery specifically. Instead, import jQuery in a source file that actually uses that library.

Comment: I think you are still struggling with the concept of entry files. I don't think you are using them correctly. Perhaps this article will help: https://css-tricks.com/introduction-webpack-entry-output-loaders-plugins/#entry